# How to make count available on .NET Channel

Tags: c#, system.threading.channels

I have an `UnboundedChannel` single reader\multiple writers and I want to be able to use `Count` property, but since `CanCount` property is always false `Count` is throwing an exception. What should i do to make it work, i can't find any restrictions enlisted in docs.

Comment: Why do you want to know that? Whatever the actual problem is probably doesn't require knowing the count. For example, to batch messages you can retrieve them one by one and add them to a local list until you reach the limit. You could also use the LINQ operators in the [System.Linq.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Async/) package along with `ChannelReader.ReadAllAsync()`,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the `UnboundedChannelOptions.SingleReader` property is set to `true` on creation, the `UnboundedChannel` implementation is `SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel`.  [Based on the source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel.cs), the `Reader` object used by this class extends [`ChannelReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/ChannelReader.cs) without explicitly setting `CanCount`, which is set to `false` by `ChannelReader` by default.

Unfortunately all these classes are sealed so you can't just extend them and implement `Count` yourself.  Leaving the `SingleReader` option as `false` will use an [`UnboundedChannelReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/UnboundedChannel.cs) implementation that does set `CanCount` to `true` and implements a `Count` method.  If you just need to check whether there are more elements in the queue, you could also use `TryPeek` instead.

Comment: Thanks, i haven't noticed i was acutally using SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel in this configuration, now with default options it works. I wonder why CanCount set to false with single reader.

Comment: @cookieMonster The implementation of [`SingleProducerConsumerQueue`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/57bfe474518ab5b7cfe6bf7424a79ce3af9d6657/src/libraries/Common/src/System/Collections/Concurrent/SingleProducerConsumerQueue.cs) implements `Count` but says "This method is not safe to use concurrently with any other members that may mutate the collection."  My best guess is that the designers decided not to expose it rather than open up the concurrency error risk.

Answer (score 2):

All bounded channel implementations support reading the [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.count), so if you need a `SingleReader` and `Count`-enabled unbounded channel you could just use a bounded channel configured with the maximum capacity. Practically it will be unbounded.

```
var channel = Channel.CreateBounded<int>(
    new BoundedChannelOptions(Int32.MaxValue) { SingleReader = true });

Console.WriteLine(channel.Reader.CanCount); // True
```

---

**Update:** Currently there is only one bounded channel implementation, the [`BoundedChannel<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/e893232556791c8f6efa069521c580427c8f1648/src/libraries/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels/BoundedChannel.cs) (internal sealed class), which ignores the [`SingleReader`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channeloptions.singlereader) setting. In other words you get the same implementation, regardless of the number of readers that you want to use. Which is a bit disappointing, because it indicates that the rich set of available options does not correspond to an equally rich set of implementations. Basically there are only three implementations available in .NET 6, the `UnboundedChannel<T>`, the `SingleConsumerUnboundedChannel<T>`, and the `BoundedChannel<T>`.